# C# code is failing - trying to get excel cell A3 value

Tags: c#, ssis

I am running this code to get value fro Cell A3 , but its giving me error .

I am using SSIS to get excel cell A3 , for now I want to show it on message box but later on I am going to store in variable.

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.CheckStateOpen(String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ValidateConnection(String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ValidateConnectionAndTransaction(String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ST_863f36c5697844e3916f1142373f3d3a.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

**Here is code**

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb; 

namespace ST_863f36c5697844e3916f1142373f3d3a.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */

        public void Main()
        {

            string connectionString = null;
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = null;

            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\NewFolder\\Test.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";";

            excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            // Currentable is the Sheetname
            string strSQL = "Select * From [" + "Sheet1$" + "A3:A3]";
            int iCnt = 4;
            OleDbCommand objcmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, excelConnection);
            //int endpos = 1;
            //int startpos = 0;
            //Boolean startflag = true;
            //Boolean flag = true;
            OleDbDataReader objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();
            int nullcount = 0;
            //  MessageBox.Show(objReader.FieldCount.ToString());
            try
            {
                //   MessageBox.Show("Before while");
                while (objReader.Read())
                {
                    // Checking for NULLS as there are blank rows in between actual Excel row data. GETVALUE(2) searches in the B column of Excel
                    if (objReader.GetValue(2) == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        nullcount = nullcount + 1;
                        // MessageBox.Show("Null");
                    }
                    if (objReader.GetValue(2) != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        //  MessageBox.Show(objReader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                        iCnt = iCnt + 1;
                    }



                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace.ToString());
            }




            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try opening the connection first

excelConnection.Open()

Answer (score 1):

You create the `OleDbConnection` object, but never call [`Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to actually establish the connection.

Answer (score 0):

U wrote:

```
string strSQL = "Select * From [" + "Sheet1$" + "A3:A3]";
```

If there is no intellegent/referenced part in the text then what's the use of + signs there in the string? Isn't that euqal to:

```
string strSQL = "Select * From [Sheet1$A3:A3]";
```

Or am I missing something there?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but the reason for the error is that the connection has not been opened.

Comment: right @Halvard I agree, but lets say we add the line to open the connection, but what will strSQL string fetch??? [Sheet1$A3:A3] is correct way?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  It returns a `SheetRange` with only one element in (everything from A3 to A3).